# An approximate algorithm for finding Steiner Forest

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, tree, approximation

Consider a weighted graph G=(V,E,w). We are given a family of subsets of vertices V_i.

A Steiner Forest is a forest that for each subset of vertices V_i connects all of the vertices in this subset with a tree.

Example: only one subset V_1 = V. In this case a Steiner forest is a spanning tree of the whole graph.

Example: a graph P4 (path with 4 vertices) and two subsets: V_1 = {v1, v4} and V_2 = {v2, v3}. The Steiner tree for this example is the whole graph.

Enough theory. Finding such a forest with minimal weight is difficult (NP-complete). Do you know any quicker approximate algorithm to find such a forest with non-optimal weight?

Comment: This *might* be appropriate for SO, but given the apparent difficulty level of the math, you might have better luck on http://mathoverflow.net.

Comment: For completeness: the same question I've asked on mo.net: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21859/an-approximate-algorithm-for-finding-steiner-forest-in-a-graph

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chapter 20 of Approximation Algorithms by Vijay Vazirani describes a schema for generating a Steiner Forest. The analysis uses LP-duality, which he uses to determine the factor of the algorithm:

(This is a factor-2 algorithm but in practice it probably fares quite well)

[Approximation Algorithms](http://books.google.com/books?id=EILqAmzKgYIC&lpg=PA27&ots=XjaTJN-Q9Z&dq=vazirani%20steiner&pg=PR17#v=onepage&q=vazirani%20steiner&f=false)

Also: see the note in 22.5 that describes three papers for further reading, including a survey of the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can restate this problem as other NP-complete, for which you know any suboptimal algorithms?
This is just a guess, though -- I can't find such mapping with my very limited math skills :)